# Watching a youtube video on training a CNN classifier,can't understand this line of code related to normalisation

Tags: python, pytorch

The code can be found here:
https://github.com/gaurav67890/Pytorch_Tutorials/blob/master/cnn-scratch-training.ipynb

In code cell number 64

```
#Transforms
transformer=transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((150,150)),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),  #0-255 to 0-1, numpy to tensors
    transforms.Normalize([0.5,0.5,0.5], # 0-1 to [-1,1] , formula (x-mean)/std
                        [0.5,0.5,0.5])
])
```

why exactly do we need to Normalize the image tensor?
also why do we pass parameters [0.5,0.5,0.5],[0.5,0.5,0.5] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalization does two things. It limits the data range and reduces the skewness. Which usually improves the learning of a ML algorithm. The data range is not necessarily needed in this example since the range is already

```
[0,-1]
```

So the answer to your first question is. We normalize to make the data smoother and bring it into the [-1,1] range.

The parameters [0.5,0.5,0.5],[0.5,0.5,0.5] are the mean and standard deviation for each of the three channels respectively. You could also calculate them based on the input image but it appears like this step was simplified.

Comment: 1:How do we know that the data range lies between  the [0,-1] range?
2:What sort of advantage is there for actually specifying the mean and standard deviation,shouldnt thouse be calculated from the actual image?

Comment: 1: The transformation happens in the codeblock you linked in the line `transforms.ToTensor(),  #0-255 to 0-1, numpy to tensors`. Usually images consist of 0-255 values for each color (RGB). Those are discrete values. Neural networks like continous values close to 0 because of their activation functions which have their peak at around 0. The NN which you referenced uses the ReLU activation fuction which changes its behaviour at x=0. So it is beneficial if your input space is around that value. Thats why they transform  to [-1,1].

Comment: 2: If you would do that then the `Normalize` function would have to calculate the mean and deviation for every image. Which would have a performance impact. Also those are hyperparameters which don't get changed during training by definition. I don't know for sure but I strongly assume thats why the developers did it this way.

Comment: If my original answer helped you please mark it as the solving answer. It would help me to keep helping people. ^^